# Toshiba Laptop Not Retaining BIOS

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop, cmos

We have a Toshiba Satellite L50-C-1FR laptop.

For some reason, one day it stopped retaining all the BIOS information (time, date, etc). The info has to be set every time it's booted. The first thing we thought was to change the CMOS battery but this model doesn't have a CMOS battery.

Also, it appears to have no pins or jumpers for a reset.

We replaced the laptop battery, the charger, the memory, the hard drive, reinstalling the OS and changing the OS but none of these replacements worked. We even tried using the replacememnts in various combinations with the original parts but this didn't work either.

We've pulled our communal hair out trying to figure this out. Can this be sorted, if so, how or do we now own a Toshiba laptop doorstop?

Comment: Did you replace the [CMOS battery](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/cmos.jpg) (image for reference)? It's not clear from your question

Comment: Ah, "battery" might not be "CMOS battery" but might be "laptop battery". Good call, @CaldeiraG.

Comment: @Arjan that's what first popped out of my mind :)

Comment: Have you moved the jumper for a CMOS reset, and left it on the wrong pins?

Comment: Would anyone know if the CMOS battery is typically also used to preserve the settings? (Rather than only for the real-time clock.)

Comment: @Arjan typically yes

Comment: Hi all. Edited the question as suggested to add relevant detail. Thanks all.

Comment: Looking at some pictures of your computer MB, it seems it's a jumper somewhere I didn't find yet. I'll have a look later :)

Answer (score -1):

I have a Toshiba L50D-B doing the same thing.

The CMOS battery is hard to get to get to and is soldered into the board, but can't be seen by just removing the bottom cover.
Instead I had to remove the motherboard from the case entirely. The small CMOS battery was located on the board... facing topside not bottomside like most laptops.
Very small battery. Soldered onto the board.
And whatever you do!........ do not touch the reset button on the board. That's how my problem started. I thought I knew what I was doing one with the back cover off, and pressed it to see what it would do!    BIG OOOPS MOMENT. Date and time reset, and keeps asking for date and time to be set every time I power up now.
You have a different Lappy,  But maybe this info will help you find your CMOS battery.